# when does Cassandra node fail?

Tags: cassandra

How does cassandra guarantee no failure of node at any given point of time,i know data is replicated so there might not be issues of losing the data

Comment: Cassandra does not guarantee a lack of node failures. It is designed to tolerate levels of node failure. This gives the total system a much better liveness as parts can fail without the whole being compromised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra nodes can fail due to alot of reasons like, very heavy write, out of memory error, hardware failure, tombstone limit 100k error, compaction failures, network errors, and so on.

Cassandra cannot guarantee no failure of node, because it just like any other software is vulnerable to dependent component and hardware.

What it does guarantee is that you won't have data loss, until you have minimum number of required nodes up and running, based on replication factor.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra could not guarantee no failure of nodes like any other systems, but with a correct setup of cassandra cluster, with enough number of nodes and replicas configured, even some of the nodes down, the entire cluster will still be available and no data lost, which could be transparent to clients. Clients will not realize it.